# Spring MVC и JPA проблема с поиском в БД

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, jpa

Есть приложение в котором есть метод поиска по разным параметрам в БД. 
Данные в метод попадают из формы через контроллер.

Форма поиска

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>

    <h1>Поиск поставок</h1>
    <c:url var="searchUrl"
        value="/supplyController/search?idProvider=${idAttribute.provider.idProvider }" />
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="idAttribute"
        method="POST" action="${searchUrl}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="provider.idProvider"></form:label></td>
                <td ><form:input
                        path="provider.idProvider" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="carNumber">Номер автомобиля:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input  path="carNumber" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="department">Отдел:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="department" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="arrivalDate">Дата прихода от:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="date" path="arrivalDate" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="arrivalDate">Дата прихода до:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input type="date" path="arrivalDate" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input value="Найти" input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form:form>
```

Если в форму ввести Номер авто и Отдел то поиск работает, но если нет какого-то одного из этих параметров(или № авто или Отдел) то поиск не работает (на страницу ничего не выводится).

Метод поиска:

```
    @Override
public List<Supply> searchByCriteria(Integer idProvider, String department, String carNumber, LocalDate startDate,
        LocalDate endDate) throws DaoException {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Supply> query = cb.createQuery(Supply.class);
        Root<Supply> supplyRoot = query.from(Supply.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
        if (idProvider != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(supplyRoot.get("provider").get("idProvider"), idProvider));
        }
        if (department != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(supplyRoot.get("department"), department));
        }
        if (carNumber != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(supplyRoot.get("carNumber"), carNumber));
        }
        if (startDate != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(supplyRoot.<LocalDate> get("arrivalDate"), startDate, endDate));
        }
        if (endDate != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.between(supplyRoot.<LocalDate> get("arrivalDate"), endDate, startDate));
        }
        query.select(supplyRoot).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

        // Predicate[] predicatesarr = predicates.toArray(new
        // Predicate[predicates.size()]);

        return manager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException("An error has occurred in class SupplyDaoImpl, method searchByCriteria.", e);
    }
}
```

И контроллер:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showSearchForm(@RequestParam(value = "idProvider", required = true) Integer idProvider, Model model)
        throws DaoException {
    Supply supply = new Supply();
    supply.setProvider(providerDao.findById(idProvider));
    model.addAttribute("idAttribute", supply);
    return "formOfSearch";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam Integer idProvider,
        @RequestParam String department,
        @RequestParam String carNumber,
        @RequestParam ("arrivalDate")@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply, Model model) throws DaoException {

    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    model.addAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
}
```

Также, посоветуйте как лучше организовать поиск в БД по разным критериям, которые могут быть как null так и нет.

Может быть можно вынести каждый критерий в отдельный метод? Как потом соединить эти методы в кучу для показа результатов?

Прошу сильно не пинать, я только учусь.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Только что пришла мысля: а что если создать на каждый критерий поиска отдельный метод, потом результаты поиска каждого метода загнать в коллекцию и уже из коллекции выводить результаты в JSP?

Comment: Уверены что, если в поле ничего не вводить, то будет null? Может получается пустая строка ""? Попробуйте `if (department != null && !department.isEmpty()) { ...`

Comment: Если нужен поиск по null, то лучше наверно генерить разные предикаты if (dep != null) { cb.equal(...); } else { cb.isNull(...); }

Comment: Проблема решилась. Действительно приходила пустая строка, а не null.